# C# Load DataTable from LinQ XDocument

Tags: c#, xpath, datatable, namespaces, linq-to-xml

I have a complex XML which is loaded into XDocument and I want to turn it into a DataTable please. Here is the actual XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<XMLCONTAINER version="1.0" incCount="3">
<APPLICATION id="APPLICATION_NODE_1" title="" name="55038170812RDOpayment" application="Excel" appfile="%SAAR%\xmlsFs\Dbxmls.xla" command="openDatabaseDesigner">
<MAINDATA id="CONTAINER_NODE_2" title=""/>
<SKY.FORM id="CONTAINER_NODE_3" title="" table="tblMain" database="\\c\E\DARA\Data\Link\RDOpayments.mdb">
  <FIELD fieldName="RID">1234567</FIELD>
  <FIELD fieldName="DateTime">05/02/2019 09:00:50</FIELD>
  <FIELD fieldName="DateOfLetter">29/01/2019</FIELD>
  <FIELD fieldName="Name">Mr Joe Bloggs</FIELD>
  <FIELD fieldName="NRID">XXX1234X</FIELD>
  <FIELD fieldName="paymentAmount">776.40</FIELD>
  <FIELD fieldName="Amountfor0809">776.40</FIELD>
  <FIELD fieldName="ACE">FALSE</FIELD>
  <FIELD fieldName="Telephone">123456789</FIELD>
  <FIELD fieldName="AcceptWithheldNumber">FALSE</FIELD>
  <FIELD fieldName="PotentialACECase">FALSE</FIELD>
  <FIELD childID="CONTAINER_NODE_3_field7option1" fieldName="CustomerType">3</FIELD>
  <FIELD fieldName="ContactHistory">05/02/2019</FIELD>
  <FIELD fieldName="ACERed">FALSE</FIELD>
</SKY.FORM>
```

The DataTable needs to look like this:

```html
RID DateTime  DateOfLetter Name  NRID paymentAmount ACE
--- -----------  ------------ ----   ---- -------------  ----------
1234567 2019-02-05 10:23:51 2019-02-05 MISS LL TEST X1234X 123.45  FALSE
7654321 2019-01-11 11:11:11 2019-02-03 MR I WONG Y4321Y 321.21  TRUE
```

My current attempts of coding this are not picking up the xml as Node? I think it should be attributes xattribute??

```
// Conversion Xml file to DataTable
    public DataTable CreateDataTableXML(string XmlFile)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

        doc.Load(XmlFile);

        DataTable Dt = new DataTable();

        try
        {
            Dt.TableName = GetTableName(XmlFile);
            XmlNode NodeStructure = doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.Cast<XmlNode>().ToList()[0];
            progressBar1.Maximum = NodeStructure.ChildNodes.Count;
            progressBar1.Value = 0;
            foreach (XmlNode column in NodeStructure.ChildNodes)
            {
                Dt.Columns.Add(column.Name, typeof(String));
                Progress();
            }

            XmlNode Xnodes = doc.DocumentElement;
            progressBar1.Maximum = Xnodes.ChildNodes.Count;
            progressBar1.Value = 0;
            foreach (XmlNode xnode in Xnodes.ChildNodes)
            {
                List<string> Values = xnode.ChildNodes.Cast<XmlNode>().ToList().Select(x => x.InnerText).ToList();
                Dt.Rows.Add(Values.ToArray());
                Progress();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
        return Dt;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally solved this. For anyone reading this, you need to solve in two parts, first get the column names into the datatable and then the xml values.

For the column names as we already have a table in sql we want to upload to, I simply used a dataadapter to fill the datatable with the schema which made sure every column name was there in the dt.

For the xml values, this proved more tricky as in a normal xml I could have just looped on the fieldname=, however as each attribute tag is different I extracted each manually with .attribute ?.value. It was a simple case then of creating datarows which would coalesce to DBNull if data was null.